# Why calling of window.setTimeout for the same function doesn't introduce infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I saw the following code:

```
class MasterControlPanel {
    private sensors: Sensor[] = [];
    constructor() {
        // Instantiating the delegate HeatSensor
        this.sensors.push(new HeatSensor(this));
    }

    start() {
        for (var i= 0; i < this.sensors.length; i++) {
            // Calling the delegate
            this.sensors[i].check();
        }
        window.setTimeout(() => this.start(), 1000);
    }

    startAlarm(message: string) {
        console.log('Alarm! ' + message);
    }
}

var cp = new MasterControlPanel();
cp.start();
```

Why `window.setTimeout(() => this.start(), 1000);` doesn't introduce infinite loop?

Based on my understanding, `cp.start()` will first iterate each `sensor` inside `sensors` and then call the `window.setTimeout` which in turn calls the `start` again after `1` second delay.

Reference: Listing 3-3. Delegation in Pro TypeScript: Application-Scale JavaScript Development

Comment: Off topic: I'm wondering what `() => this.start()` does - must be some funky new JS syntax I'm not familiar with!

Comment: That's a lambda, it's new in ES6.

Comment: It does introduce an infinite loop. It's just 1 second between iteratiions.

Comment: An analog of your code produces a loop in my browser console.  `function x(i) { console.log(i); window.setTimeout(() => x(i+1), 1000); }`.  I suspect its not looping in your case because the "this" keyword might not resolve to the class instance.

Answer (score 2):

In short, it doesn't introduce an infinite loop because setTimeout doesn't block.  Instead, the function you give it to execute, () => this.start() is added to a queue and executed after 1 second of time passes.  The start method returns after calling window.setTimeout, and thus doesn't cause an infinite loop in the imperative sense.  Most of the time, the code will be in a state of waiting until the next timer comes up.

That the code infinitely schedules a timer to call the start method is also true, but it isn't an infinite loop because it returns control to the javascript runtime.

Answer (score 1):

It does introduce an infinite loop, delayed 1 sec between each call

```
window.setTimeout(() => this.start(), 1000);
```

is almost the same as

```
var _this = this; 
window.setTimeout(function(){ _this.start(); }, 1000);
```

it's called [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need `setInterval`.
That one would create a infinite loop which you can clear by using `clearInterval`.

```
this.interval = window.setInterval(() => {
...
}, 5000);

window.clearInterval(this.interval);
```

Also you can do

```
this.sensors.forEach(sensor => sensor.check())
```

Instead of using `for` loop.

Comment: Downvoted for not answering the question. The question asker asked why the code in question was not looping infinitely, not how to make it do so. On top of that, the example code you gave does exactly the same thing as the OP's code.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use this in the setTimeout, because it refers to the setTimeout, not to your class. 
Try this :

```
class MasterControlPanel {
    private sensors: Sensor[] = [];
    constructor() {
        // Instantiating the delegate HeatSensor
        this.sensors.push(new HeatSensor(this));
    }
    var that = this;
    start() {
        for (var i= 0; i < this.sensors.length; i++) {
            // Calling the delegate
            this.sensors[i].check();
        }
        window.setTimeout(() => that.start(), 1000);
    }

    startAlarm(message: string) {
        console.log('Alarm! ' + message);
    }
}

var cp = new MasterControlPanel();
cp.start();
```

Comment: Context of setTimeout is actually window. And it's because cp.start() was executed in window scope.
Also, start = () => can be used within classes to automatically bind the class context.

Comment: Downvoted for incorrect information. You CAN use this in the function closure, because it uses fat arrow syntax, which binds to the outer scope.